# how to convert c# objects to cosmosDb document?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb, xunit

I was using Cosmonaut in build library function to convert the c# objects to cosmosDb document like this:

```
var document = fakeUser.ConvertObjectToDocument();
```

Now I want to remove the cosmonaut library. Is there any other way to convert c# objects to cosmosdb documents?

Answer (score 2):

Simply copy Cosmonaut's code for the method and remove what you don't need. The following will work.

```
public static Document ConvertObjectToDocument<TEntity>(this TEntity obj) where TEntity : class
{
    var dynamicDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));

    using (JsonReader reader = new JTokenReader(dynamicDoc))
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.LoadFrom(reader);
        return document;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To write a C# class (called `yourClass`) to DocumentDB as a document, simply do something like this:

```
await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), yourClass);
```

You can find more information on working with DocumentDB here: [Azure Cosmos DB: SQL API getting started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started), and more specifically [Step 6: Create JSON Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#CreateDoc).